# Bootstrap-Selectpicker dropdown not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-select

So I'm using the bootstrap selectpicker plugin for my application, and for some reason the div that holds the list of options will not display when the button is clicked. However, it works if I type a letter that corresponds with one of the options from the list.

Here's my jQuery

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        size: 8
    });
```

And here is the code for my dropdown list

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerName, Model.CustomerList, new { @class = "selectpicker form-control", @id = "cust", multiple="multiple", data_actions_box="true" })
```

I can type `$('.dropdown-menu').show();` into the console in Chrome while running, and it force displays the div. This could be wrapped in a `.click` function to make it work, but it shouldn't need to be, right?

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong here, I'm definitely a jQuery novice.

Any ideas on what might be causing this/how to fix?

Comment: can you create a regular `<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true"><option>Mustard</option><option>Ketchup</option></select>` and see if it works with a non htmlhelper generated dropdown?

Comment: @JamieD77 Exact same results, menu won't display until I hit a key.

Comment: seems strange.. i've seen issues where there were 2 references to javascript / boostrap.js on the same page that when you click something the click event gets fired twice and you dont see it open and close but it does..

Comment: @JamieD77 I think you may be on to something... Started pulling Scripts.Render functions from my layout, and adding them manually to the page where the form is, and I got it working. Just need to find out which script is causing this issue.

Comment: Hey can you please explain to me how you made it work I think I´m going crazy! I have the exact same issue and been trying to figure it out for hours!! It doesn't work until I hit a key as well.

Comment: @user2081044 If I recall correctly, some of the included scripts in my MVC application were conflicting with the bootstrap-selectpicker. Try removing the reference to any other .js files from the page until you find the one that is making the conflict. (I believe that's what I did) Hope this helps!

Comment: @j76 Wow that was it! You're a lifesaver, thank you very much sir!

Comment: Interesting - I had the same behaviour and it was the same cause - thanks @JamieD77